# Inflater fail on some Android L devices - NotFoundException - mix drawable with other types

Tags: android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

Any idea what could cause this error :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class net.ebt.appswitch.view.AppIconView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:629)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:410)
       ...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "android:style/TextAppearance.MisspelledSuggestion" (10302fd)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x10302fd a=1 r=0x10302fd}
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2325)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2265)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:743)
       at android.view.View.(View.java:3693)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:487)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:105)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:101)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:97)
       ...
```

I am not using TextAppearance.MisspelledSuggestion in any of my resources. **It happen only on L**.

Here the layout :

```
<x.x.x.MyCustomViewExtendsFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/icon_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/MyAppTheme.TextAppearance.Black.Shadow"
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/icon_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/icon_padding"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/icon_text_size"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_picto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/icon_badge_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_pin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/icon_badge_size" />

</x.x.x.MyCustomViewExtendsFrameLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the XML for your layout look like? Are you applying any styles to the view?

Comment: I've just added the layout in the description, thanks !

Comment: Does this still occur if you use a standard FrameLayout instead of a custom class?

Comment: Very hard to tell, I cannot reproduce the issue on my end, I only see the crashes in my crash reporting tool (production).

Comment: Is it from an L preview release? The actual release has different framework resource IDs from the preview, which could explain this. Do you know any details about the exact device or version?

Comment: I hope it is a preview issue. Version reported is L (in crashlytics), device are Nexus7/Nexus5. Does the second preview released in October could have the problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64442/discussion-between-ebtokyo-and-alanv).